# Java - Reversing the way the output is shown

Tags: java, file-io, output, reverse

This is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Created by Luis on 09/09/2015.
 */
public class ReadToHashmap {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Integer> mapofstuff = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Luis\\Desktop\\Java.POO\\testingide\\src\\la2\\grades.txt"));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String parts[] = line.split(" ", 2);

            int part1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

            if(mapofstuff.containsKey(parts[0])) {
                mapofstuff.put(parts[0], mapofstuff.get(parts[0])+part1);
            }

            else {
                mapofstuff.put(parts[0], part1);
            }
        }
        in.close();


        System.out.println(entriesSortedByValues(mapofstuff));
    }


    public static <K,V extends Comparable<? super V>>
    SortedSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> entriesSortedByValues(Map<K,V> map) {
        SortedSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> sortedEntries = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<K,V>>(
                new Comparator<Map.Entry<K,V>>() {
                    @Override public int compare(Map.Entry<K,V> e1, Map.Entry<K,V> e2) {
                        int res = e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
                        return res != 0 ? res : 1;
                    }
                }
        );
        sortedEntries.addAll(map.entrySet());
        return sortedEntries;
    }
}
```

This is what file "grades.txt" contains:

```
10885 10
70000 6
70000 10
60000 4
70000 4
60000 4
10885 10
60001 5
60002 8
60003 8
```

And it produces this output:

```
[60001=5, 60000=8, 60002=8, 60003=8, 10885=20, 70000=20]
```

This is output I desire:

```
[70000=20, 10885=20, 60003=8, 60002=8, 60000=8, 60001=5]
```

Effectively reversing the output I have at the moment.
Thank you for your time.

Aditional Info:

The **"grades.txt"** contains for each column (**"Number_of_student"**, **partial_grade**) for multiple students.

I want to read the file and for each student add **all partial grades** of a given student to a **final grade**, so I end up with (**"Number_of_student"**, **final_grade**) for each.

Then I want to order it by **descending order of final_grade**, and **if** students have the same final_grade, order them by **descending order of the Number_of_student**.

Comment: You can change your comparable to other way around return res == 0 ? res : 1

Comment: @DreadfulWeather No son I had already tried that and it gives me this output: [10885=20, 60000=8, 60001=5, 70000=20]

Comment: Well you can also use collections.reverse but i dont think it would be effective so you should try to change that comparator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few corrections:

1. Since you're using the key as a secondary index you should convert it to an integer as well.
2. Since you want to use the key as the secondary sorting value, the last line in the comparison function should be changed respectively (see example below)
3. Since you want to sort in reverse order, the comparison function should return the opposite result, that is `-` (minus sign) before the result.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<Integer, Integer> mapofstuff = new TreeMap<>();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\Java.POO\testingide\src\la2\grades.txt"));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String parts[] = line.split(" ", 2);

        int part0 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0].trim());
        int part1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1].trim());

        if(mapofstuff.containsKey(part0)) {
            mapofstuff.put(part0, mapofstuff.get(part0) + part1);
        }

        else {
            mapofstuff.put(part0, part1);
        }
    }
    in.close();


    System.out.println(entriesSortedByValues(mapofstuff));
}


public static <K,V extends Comparable<? super V>>
SortedSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> entriesSortedByValues(Map<K,V> map) {
    SortedSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> sortedEntries = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<K,V>>(
            new Comparator<Map.Entry<K,V>>() {
                @Override public int compare(Map.Entry<K,V> e1, Map.Entry<K,V> e2) {
                    int res = -e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
                    return res != 0 ? res : -((Integer)e1.getKey()).compareTo((Integer)e2.getKey());
                }
            }
    );
    sortedEntries.addAll(map.entrySet());
    return sortedEntries;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[70000=20, 10885=20, 60003=8, 60002=8, 60000=8, 60001=5]
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you! I apologize for my language on the other comment I agree It was rude and unnecessary since @DreadfulWeather was only trying to help the cause. I added the aditional info your wisdom advised(a bit late) and when I finished the edit I saw your answer, and It was exactly what I wanted. Cheers!